# How to set rotateX around a center point?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to set the rotateX property of a movie clip (so it tilts backwards in 3d), but whenever I attempt it with

```
myMC.rotationX = -90;
```

it tilts back at an odd angle. How can I rotate the movieclip so that it leans backwards perfectly straight? How do I set a center point for this transform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A screenshot would be helpful to explain "...an odd angle" but it sounds like your 'vanishing point' is in the wrong place. Take a look at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/PerspectiveProjection.html

You set the vanishing point on the parent (only needs to be done once, unless you wish to move it or stage resizes), eg:

```
//set vanishing point to center of current DisplayObject
this.projectionCenter = new Point(this.width/2, this.height/2);
```

Then rotate:

```
myMC.rotationX = -90;
```

Comment: I'm getting an undefined property on this.projectionCenter. Did you mean this.transform.perspectiveProjection.projectionCenter?